# SQL Server UTC timestamp

Tags: sql-server

I have stored procedure which inserts data into some table. There is a column say pick up time (datatype `datetime`). Now the time is in `datetime` format I want the stored procedure to store `datetime` to UTC zone timing.

How to do it in the stored procedure?

Comment: What you have tried so far that didn't work ? Please show what you attempted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to get the UTC time. Which you use depends on what you need:

```sql
SELECT GETUTCDATE(), --datetime
       SYSUTCDATETIME(), --datetime2(7)
       SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'; --datetimeoffset(7)
```

Comment: How to convert datetime value coming (by calling stored procedure(inserts data in table) from my application)  to UTC format ?

Comment: Provided that the value arriving is a `datetimeoffset`, @RinkuKhedar , then with `AT TIME ZONE` as I demonstrate above. If not, you can't; you have no idea what time zone the time is for and thus can't convert it to UTC.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple to achieve using [`GETUTCDATE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getutcdate-transact-sql) as shown:

```
SELECT GETUTCDATE()
```

Output:

```
2021-06-02 12:55:01.213
```

As per the description in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getutcdate-transact-sql):

> Returns the current database system timestamp as a datetime value. The
> database time zone offset is not included. This value represents the
> current UTC time (Coordinated Universal Time). This value is derived
> from the operating system of the computer on which the instance of SQL
> Server is running.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GETUTCDATE()` function in the `Insert` statement inside your stored procedure:

```
Insert into MyTable (PickUp_Col) 
values (GETUTCDATE() )
```

Comment: but GETUTCDATE will give me current timestamp

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT GETDATE() AS PickUpTime, GETUTCDATE() AS UTCTime
```

[image: Picture]