# Trigger event on database column time based

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-sql-database

I am developing an application in which I want to trigger Azure Function based on a timestamp in database column, Timestamp columns of different rows can have different time schedules. Is it possible to use some feature in database itself or from Azure to invoke function when utc time matched with time in column of database. If any AI can be used for this?

Sample Data:

[image]

Now based on time in a row and azure function should be triggered, I want Database itself automatically check UTC time and compare with Time column and trigger event

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67805488/sql-server-utc-timestamp . Just insert a column with `GETUTCDATE()` in it

Comment: This would not help me in triggering event I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a Stored Procedure or a [Trigger Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-azure-sql-trigger?pivots=programming-language-csharp&tabs=in-process%2Cportal) that in case of a specific timestamp makes a call to an Azure Function.

In order to call an Azure Function from within the Azure SQL Database you can use [sp_invoke_external_rest_endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76105598/sp-invoke-external-rest-endpoint-connections-to-the-domain-are-not-allowed)

Comment: Goal is to AutoTrigger function when UTC time matches the time specified in columns of rows ,above cannot achieve that

Comment: UTC time I can get but how it will be compared with time in columns it should be auto comparable and trigger Azure function

Comment: Sorry, can you rephrase that? I don't understand the problem. Can you use this https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables to upload a sample of the data?

Comment: @bhupinder, I still don't understand, you want the action to be trigged when `Time` = `TimeZone` --> trig ? You mean when the two columns have the same value?

Comment: Time - UTC - Tigger, same on n number of columns -> then execute function